# ASP.NET System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor

Tags: asp.net

I am getting the following error on my unit tests on my ASP.NET when running `dotnet test on VSCode` Core and I can't find out how to fix it:

```
Con error OperatorCashRetailApi.Tests.Controllers.PlayerControllerTests.GetPlayerAsync_ReturnsUnprocessableEntity_WhenMultiplePlayersFound [1 ms]
  Mensaje de error:
   System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  Seguimiento de la pila:
     at OperatorCashRetailApi.Tests.Controllers.PlayerControllerTests..ctor() in C:\Users\uceca\Desktop\Orenes\Plataforma Iris\iris\Api\CashRetailApi\CashRetailApi.Tests\Controllers\PlayerControllerTests.cs:line 33
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean wrapExceptions)
```

It seems like it can't create the PlayerController object. I tried to create an empty constructor of that object but it's also not working.

My test code:

```
public class PlayerControllerTests
{
    private readonly Mock<IConfiguration> _configurationMock;
    private readonly Mock<IPlayerService> _playerServiceMock;
    private readonly Mock<IDepositService> _depositServiceMock;
    private readonly Mock<IWithdrawalService> _withdrawalServiceMock;
    private readonly Mock<SessionService> _sessionServiceMock;
    private readonly PlayerController _controller;

    public PlayerControllerTests()
    {
        _configurationMock = new Mock<IConfiguration>();
        _playerServiceMock = new Mock<IPlayerService>();
        _depositServiceMock = new Mock<IDepositService>();
        _withdrawalServiceMock = new Mock<IWithdrawalService>();
        _controller = new PlayerController(_configurationMock.Object, _playerServiceMock.Object, _depositServiceMock.Object, _withdrawalServiceMock.Object, _sessionServiceMock.Object);
    }

[Fact]
    public async Task GetPlayerAsync_ReturnsUnprocessableEntity_WhenMultiplePlayersFound()
    {
        // Arrange
        var authToken = "testAuthToken";
        var dni = "testDni";
        var email = "testEmail";
        var request = new Mock<HttpRequest>();
        var response = new Mock<HttpResponse>();
        var httpContext = new Mock<HttpContext>();
        httpContext.Setup(x => x.Request).Returns(request.Object);
        httpContext.Setup(x => x.Response).Returns(response.Object);
        var claim = new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, authToken);
        var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(new[] { claim }, "TestAuthType");
        var claimsPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity);
        _controller.ControllerContext = new ControllerContext
        {
            HttpContext = new DefaultHttpContext { User = claimsPrincipal }
        };
        var players = new List<PlayerData>()
            {
                new PlayerData(),
                new PlayerData()
            };
        _playerServiceMock.Setup(x => x.GetPlayersAsync(authToken, It.IsAny<string>(), dni, email)).ReturnsAsync(players);

        // Act
        var result = await _controller.GetPlayerAsync(dni, email);
        var statusCodeResult = result as StatusCodeResult;

        // Assert
        Assert.NotNull(statusCodeResult);
        Assert.Equal((int)HttpStatusCode.UnprocessableEntity, statusCodeResult.StatusCode);
    }
```

PlayerController constructor:

```
private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
    private readonly IPlayerService _playerService;
    private readonly ISessionService _sessionService;
    private readonly IDepositService _depositService;
    private readonly IWithdrawalService _withdrawalService;

    private static readonly log4net.ILog log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod()?.DeclaringType);


    public PlayerController(IConfiguration configuration, IPlayerService playerService, IDepositService depositService, IWithdrawalService withdrawalService,
    ISessionService sessionService)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
        _playerService = playerService;
        _depositService = depositService;
        _withdrawalService = withdrawalService;
        _sessionService = sessionService;
    }
```

What am I missing here?

Thanks!